# D3 hierarchy chart zoom out

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy

I'm using a d3 hierarchy chart for a kiosk application. I use [this blog](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) for implimenting zoom functionality. This will enable zoom on scroll and double click. I need a way to *zoom out* on whatever way possible. A mouse cant help as this is a Kiosk application. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178366/d3-js-set-initial-zoom-level) answer to set an initial zoom

Comment: @downvoter.. what is wrong?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the initial zoom so that the entire tree is visible after it loads?

Comment: I set the initial zoom. my users wont have a mouse. they can zoom in by double tap which is a functionality d3 provides. I need a way to zoom out.

Answer (score -1):

Since the device is to ask as a Kiosk, I believe there's not mouse involved?

If that's true, you'd be left with only touch gestures for any kind of input.

You could:

1. Create a button to zoom in/out
2. Create a slider to adjust zoom levels
3. If device supports multi-touch, you can use the pinch-gesture

Comment: there is no mouse involved and that is why i cant scroll