# force layout save zoom scale in the session: d3.event.scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a force layout with a zooming behavior.

```
var min_zoom = 0.3;
var max_zoom = 3;
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([min_zoom,max_zoom]);
```

Before form submission, zooming (using the mouse wheel) and translation work just fine just as expected.

```
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" +  d3.event.scale + ")" );
```

To this end, life is good.

When the form is submitted, the current `translate` and `scale` values are saved to the session. As an example, say that the current `scale` is `2`. After the submission of the form and loading the page again, the saved `scale` is applied, restoring the zoom to its state before submission.

However, after this loading of the page, the value for `d3.event.scale` is set again to its initial value (I guess it is `1`). Hence, trying to perform an in or out zoom again (using mouse wheel) applies the scale factor to the initial base value of the zoom (supposedly `1` for `d3.event.scale`), instead of using the values saved from the session `2`, and will make a sudden, unexpected change of the zoom.

PS. Trying to manually assign a value to `d3.event.scale` doesn't work! I think the most straightforward workaround would be altering `d3.event.scale` in case that's possible. Otherwise, manually controlling the zoom seems an exhaustive and non-intuitive option to take.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178366/d3-js-set-initial-zoom-level

Comment: It does the trick... Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it... Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3.js Set initial zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178366/d3-js-set-initial-zoom-level)

Answer (score 0):

At the creation of your SVG, you need to adjust the transform of your main group as well as set the scale of your zoom.

```js
const previousScale = 2;

const min_scale = 0.3;
const max_scale = 3;

const width = 600;
const height = 200;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scale(previousScale)
  .scaleExtent([min_scale, max_scale])
  .on('zoom', redraw)

const svg = d3.select('svg')

const g = svg
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `scale(${previousScale}, ${previousScale})`)
  .call(zoom)

function draw() {
  g.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 50)
    .attr('cx', 50)
    .attr('cy', 50)

  const initialScale = zoom.scale();
  console.log(`initialScale: ${initialScale}`)
}
draw()

function redraw() {
  const newScale = zoom.scale();
  g.attr('transform', `scale(${newScale}, ${newScale})`)
  console.clear()
  console.log(`newScale: ${newScale.toFixed(2)}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```