# How to set initial position and scale when using d3.zoom()

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I have the following code working;

```
const svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .call(
    d3
      .zoom()
      .wheelDelta(this.delta)
      .on("zoom", function() {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
      })
  )
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "tree-container");
```

I later add a d3 tree layout insode the g.tree-container. The initial tree node is drawn in top left. Ideally I would like the initial node somewhere near the center of the svg

I have look here; 
[D3.js Set initial zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178366/d3-js-set-initial-zoom-level)

but can't get it to work with my code and I don't really understand what is going on.

(i believe i am using d3 version 5.7)